# Problem with Estimating the parameters value of gamma distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

can anyone please help me with this problem? I am trying to estimate parameters of gamma distribution (fitted into a set of data). Following are my command and the output produced by mathematica:

```
In[41]:= EstimatedDistribution[data, GammaDistribution[alpha, beta], ParameterEstimator -> "MethodOfMoments"]
```

and it gives me:

```
During evaluation of In[41]:= EstimatedDistribution::ntsprt: One or more data points are not in support of the distribution GammaDistribution[alpha,beta]. >>
```

I do not understand the message above and what is the cause of it? Is it because of my command or my data? *note: if i am using binomial, NB, poisson and geometric, I can get the results.

my data:

```
data = Join[ConstantArray[0, 96978], ConstantArray [1, 9240], ConstantArray [2, 704], ConstantArray [3, 43], ConstantArray [4, 9]].
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what your data looks like.

Comment: my data is something like this: data = Join[ConstantArray[0, 96978], ConstantArray [1, 9240], 
  ConstantArray [2, 704], ConstantArray [3, 43], ConstantArray [4, 9]]. thanks!

Comment: "my data is something like this" - please edit your question to include this.

Comment: BTW: have you seen `FindDistributionParameters[]`?

Comment: yup, same result. btw, what is the difference between FindDistributionParameters[] and EstimatedDistribution[]?

Comment: I think the problem is the first set, the one containing `0`; the distribution has support `x>0`. Try changing `0` to some small number.

Comment: wow that works. however I dont think I can change it to other number than 0, as it represent the frequency. :(

Comment: The support of a distribution is the set of numbers that it is defined over. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)
This should help make the meaning of the error message more clear.

Comment: @user1525225 Then probably you should consider other distributions.

Comment: Sorry, folks, I did not see your comments before I made my post and my edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the Probability Distribution Function of the Gamma Distribution:

```
PDF[GammaDistrbution[a,b], x]
```

[image]

you see that x must be larger than 0, so no zeros in your data!

Edit: I would like to point out that your data is clearly discrete data, and so take a look at the Discrete Distributions (like PoissonDistribution).  If you were to continue along the path of trying to fit this data to a Gamma Distribution with all of those zeros, then you would probably need to a) define a censored distribution:

```
censoredDistribution=CensoredDistribution[ {1,Infinity}, GammaDistribution[a,b] ];
```

and b) censor your data to remove the zeros:

```
censoredData=Select[ data, ( # >= 1 ) & ];
```

But I think this may be a waste of time, as well, as the computation may prove prohibitive and equally unjustifiable.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Sorry, I did not see your comments.